# How do I set a max width for ContextMenuStrip items, so autosizes downwards rather than across?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

How do I set a max width for ContextMenuStrip items, so autosizes downwards rather than across?

Code:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.Click
    ItemNameToolStripMenuItem.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried docking it to the Left or Right of the form?

Comment: Its docked on the right of the form... How does that impact what I'm trying to accomplish above?

Comment: Well, if you had it docked to the top, it'd be a good place to start.

Comment: I meant on the right, at the top